# Как найти ключ в словаре по значению, который заранее не известен

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно вывести ключ словаря, совпадающий по значению с элементами списка *alph* (output: cbb), но не получается.

```
alph_dict = {'a': '%', 'b': '&', 'c': '*'}
alph = ["*", "&", "&"]

for i in alph:
    if i in alph_dict.values():
        print(alph_dict.get(i))
```

Он почему-то выдает:

```
None
None
None
```

Если пишу так, то он выдает мне просто *cb*, вместо *cbb*:

```
for k, i in alph_dict.items():
    if i in alph:
        print(k, end="")
```

Как быть? Неужели нужно менять ключи и значения местами или заводить другой словарь или список со значениями? Простого и прямого способа для этого нет?

Comment: а где вы вторую b нашли? У вас один такой ключ в словаре, код который внизу вопроса работает правильно

Comment: Да, мне кажется, придётся делать обратный словарь, иначе простого способа нет, какой-то изврат получается

Comment: @CameL Имеется в виду, что в `alph` символ `&` два раза встречается, поэтому нужно два раза повторить. Да ещё и порядок вывода сделать как в `alph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Он почему-то выдает:
>
> ```
> None
> None
> None
> ```

Потому что метод `get` возвращает из словаря значение по ключу, но не наоборот. Если попытаться передать туда что-то, чего нет среди ключей, то метод вернет `None`. Вы туда передаете `"*"`, `"&"`, `"&"`, а ключи - `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, соответственно получаете три раза `None`.

Проще всего такие задачи решаются через инвертированный словарь - нужно создать новый словарь, где ключ и значения стоят наоборот:

```
alph_dict = {'a': '%', 'b': '&', 'c': '*'}
alph = ["*", "&", "&"]

alph_dict_inverted = {value: key for key, value in alph_dict.items()}

for i in alph:
    print(alph_dict_inverted[i])
```

```
c
b
b
```

Можно использовать модуль [bidict](https://pypi.org/project/bidict/), который реализует двусторонний словарь (откуда можно брать как значения по ключам, так и ключи по значниям):

```
from bidict import bidict

alph_dict = bidict({'a': '%', 'b': '&', 'c': '*'})
alph = ["*", "&", "&"]

for i in alph:
    print(alph_dict.inverse[i])
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам! :) Так и сделаю. Но странно, конечно, что приходится изворачиваться и нет прямого способа обращения к неизвестным значениям словаря.

Comment: Проблема, что при наличии одинаковых значений при инверсии словаря получим сплющивание ключей.

Comment: @AndyPavlov, так это проблема в любом случае будет, если будут дублирующиеся значения. Но по вопросу можно предположить, что ключи и значения всегда соотносятся 1 к 1.

Comment: @Kris, это не такая уж частая задача, чтобы для нее было готовое решение в стандартном словаре или в стандартной библиотеке. Обычный словарь реализуется через структуру данных [хэш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), в обычной хэш-таблице нет простого способа по значению получить ключ.

Comment: @Kris, а, ну еще не в любом словаре можно однозначно по значению найти ключ (когда значения дублируются). В bidict стоит ограничение, что и ключи и значения должны быть уникальны и хэшируемы, для обычного словаря уникальными и хэшируемыми должны быть только ключи.

Comment: @Kris, кстати, если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Comment: понятно теперь, спасибо!
@insolor, галку поставила:)